# How to fix problems with double typing when use IEDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a very strange behavior via IE Driver 32 bit. For example I input "Hello! My name is Maria." But result is:

[image]

I've tried to use 64 bit, but the result is the same. 
Has anyone else come across this problem?

My environment: Windows 10, C#+SpecFlow, WebDriver.IEDriverServer.win32, IE(11.608).

Comment: Hello Dima, welcome to StackOverflow.
It would be nice to have some code examples in questions. It will help other participants to better understand your problem and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For me downgrading of IEDriverServer on version 3.2.0 solved problem.